# fs.createReadStream() equivalent for remote file in Node

Tags: node.js

Is there an equivelate method to fs.createReadStream() in Node for remote files? Using as follows throws `Unhandled 'error' event`

```
var s = fs.createReadStream('some_mp3_url');
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Node is no PHP :)

Use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module:

```
request('http://fromrussiawithlove.com/baby.mp3').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('song.mp3'))
```

Comment: "Node is no PHP" - you made my day :-))

Comment: How do you save the result to a var like in the original question?

Answer (score 20):

It could be better to use a module like <strike>request</strike> ([alternatives](https://github.com/request/request)), but you could do it like this:

**ES6 version**

```
http.get('some_mp3_url', res => res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('some.mp3')));
```

**ES5 version**

```
http.get('some_mp3_url', function (res) {
  res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('some.mp3'));
});
```

Note: besides `fs`, the `http` (or `https`) module also has to be imported/required.

Comment: This looks almost identical to the `request` syntax — why is `request` better than the plain Node.js?

Comment: One example: http/https handling. You'll need to do this yourself in the example above. The ˋhttpˋ module doesn't handle https. ˋrequestˋ does this for you. And there will plenty of other use cases where it provides significant extra value.

Comment: yeah, but I prefer not having 22 dependencies, thanks.

Comment: I think you should think of reasons not to use the native http request before jumping to the request module. There are +600 issues with the request module as of right now, one of which is impacting my app in production. Switching back to native http requests resolved my issue. I like having control over what is happening rather than relying on a dependency to play nice all of the time, imo.

Comment: @Codler I assume you mean you want a **string** with the contents of the remote file? This wasn't part of the original question. I'd post that as a separate question, but you can find an answer in the [example](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback) inside the Node.js docs.