# node.js how to read file in stream from remote server

Tags: node.js

In node.js I am trying to watch and read a text file on filechange.For this, I am using below code and it is working absolutely fine.

```
var fs = require('fs'),bite_size = 256,readbytes = 0,file;
fs.open('testread.txt', 'r', function(err, fd) {
    file = fd; //readsome(); 

    var func = (function readsome() {
    var stats = fs.fstatSync(file); // yes sometimes async does not make sense!
    if(stats.size<readbytes+1) {        
        setTimeout(readsome, 1000);
    }
    else {
        fs.read(file, new Buffer(bite_size), 0, bite_size, readbytes, function (err, bytecount, buff) {
        console.log(buff.toString('utf-8', 0, bytecount));
        readbytes+=bytecount;
        process.nextTick(readsome);
        });
    }
    })();   
});
```

But this works only for local file and now I need to read text file from remote server ( may be linux or windows) in same way.

Please help , how can I use remote server login information like below

```
IP address = "XXX.XXX.XX.XX";, 
username = username, 
password = password, 
filepath = "/root/testread.txt" or "D:\testread.txt"
```

and read the data from text file present at filepath in remote server.

Comment: To access file from remote you can use [REQUEST MODULE](https://github.com/request/request)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544911/fs-createreadstream-equivalent-for-remote-file-in-node

Comment: Thanks @J4GD33P 51NGH,  The "request" module looks promising but I am not getting idea how to use it, especially how to give server IP. Could you you please refer me with some working code with IP, user and password. Thanks

Comment: Why you want to login first. simply place file in www root path of remote server and access it from url.

Comment: ok I will put file /root/testread.txt but where to put IP address of remote server ? That is confusing me.I am trying to use ,request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password',
    'sendImmediately': false
  }
});

Comment: you able to access files placed in remote server from browser directly? if yes then in your code, you can also access directly with url. no need to give ip password

Comment: I am not able to. Actually I didn't try that. I may try if you please refer me something.

Comment: Your remote server is linux? LAMP is installed in it? if yes then place your file in /var/www/html directory then access through url in browser like: YOUR_SERVER_IP/filename.txt

Comment: Hi @J4GD33P 51NGH, I do not have LAMP installed and my remote servers are linux and windows both.

Comment: Then [INSTALL](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

`fs` uses the local filesystem.
To access remote files, you need to use some `network protocol` (**NTFS for Windows and SSH or FTP for Linux**).
Those `protocols` expose files to remote access, you cannot access the filesystem of a remote host not using them.

Comment: Thanks @dima, I have ssh enabled for linux server. Would be a great help if you please refer me some working code/example for reading file from remote server.